# Best way to maintain only one schema between Mongoose and Joi

Tags: node.js, mongoose, hapi.js, joi, mongoose-schema

I'm using Hapi to develop a web service, with Mongoose as ODM and Joi as validator. 
I really like Joi's validation and the way it connects with HAPI (I need Joi's description function to display some description in swagger) but I don't want to maintain two schemas, one for Joi and one for mongoose; I would like to define my schema using Joi and then being able to export only the basic schema required by Mongoose. For example:

**mySchema.js**

```
module.exports = {
    name : String,
    address: String
}
```

**myValidator.js**

```
module.exports = {
    payload: {
        name: Joi.description('A name').string().required(),
        address: Joi.description('An address').string()
    }
}
```

**myModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    mySchema = require('./mySchema');

var schemaInstance = new mongoose.Schema(mySchema),
    myModel = mongoose.model('myModel', schemaInstance);
```

**myHapiRoute.js**

```
const myValidator = require('./myValidator.js'),
    myController = require('./myController.js');

...

{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/create',
    config: {
        description: 'create something',
        tags: ['api'],
        handler: myController,
        validate: myValidator
    }
}
...
```

I would like to avoid the hassle to maintain **mySchema.js** file generating it **exactly** from Joi's schema.

Any suggestions on how to do it or any different approaches?

Comment: Why use joi for validation when Mongoose as schema valdiation built-in?

Comment: I need different validations for different HTTP request. What is mandatory for a POST request could be not mandatory for a PUT request

Comment: Ok that is why I don't use mongoose and wrote my own [module](https://github.com/simon-p-r/wadofgum-mongodb)

Comment: Its funny to me that you ask this today, I found your question on Google when I was Googling the same thing.  Kudos to them for the rapid indexing. I found this module on github when I was digging around:  https://github.com/yoitsro/joigoose   I have not attempted to use it yet, but so far it seems like the most promising option. (unless you want to build it yourself)

Comment: You can use this method https://gist.github.com/stongo/6359042

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this matter you could use [Joigoose](https://github.com/yoitsro/joigoose) to convert your Joi schema to a Mongoose schema as the example below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const joi = require('joi')
const joigoose = require('joigoose')(mongoose)

const joiSchema = joi.object().keys({
  name: joi.description('A name').string().required(),
  address: joi.description('An address').string()
})

const mongooseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(joigoose.convert(joiSchema))

mongose.model('Model', mongooseSchema)
```

Comment: 2 year late, but at least it could be helpful for someone with the same question lol

Comment: TypeError: joi.description(...).string is not a function

Comment: Be careful with this package. It is not being maintained. For new mongoose it will quickly become incompatible.